# Polynomial roots locus

Tags: polynomials

Let $Q_1,Q_2(z)$ be a pair of polynomials with complex coefficients. Let $S$ be a curve that passes through all roots of both polynomials. For a $t\in S$ define polynomial

$$ Q_t(z) = Q_1(z) Q_2(t) - Q_1(t) Q_2(z) $$

When there is such an $S$ that for any $t \in S$ all roots of   $Q_t(z)$ lie on $S$?

Comment: Do you have any examples of $Q_1,Q_2$ for which there is such an $S$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson   Yes, when their roots are interleaved on the interval [ -1,1]

Comment: And what is the $S$ that works in that case, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson the interval [-1,1]